# Disable SSL in Azure API APP

Tags: api, azure, post, https

I have a device that sends POST REQUEST to a Azure API App. However, my device (ThingSee), does not support HTTPs endpoints, I need to disable SSL somehow or obtain a HTTP endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way of using an API App as a HTTP endpoint. However, Web Apps runs in a very similar environment as API Apps, and Web Apps have a HTTP endpoint by default. I didn't even have to change anything, I basically just deployed the API in a Web App.